# handsontable - maxRows - remove rows option disabled

Tags: handsontable

I would like to create a table with the option maxRows. But when I use this option and the table have reached the max row count the option "remove row" within the context menu is disabled. Does anybody know why this option is getting disabled when the table have reached the max count of rows?

Example code:

```
var myData = [
 ["", "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda"],
 ["2008", 10, 11, 12, 13],
 ["2009", 20, 11, 14, 13],
 ["2010", 30, 15, 12, 13]
],
container = document.querySelector('#exampleGrid');

var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
 data: myData,
 startRows: 5,
 startCols: 5,
 minSpareCols: 1,
 //always keep at least 1 spare row at the right
 minSpareRows: 1,
 //always keep at least 1 spare row at the bottom,
 maxRows:8,
 rowHeaders: true,
 colHeaders: true,
 contextMenu: true
});
```